# Faster exponentiation of complex arrays in Python using Arrayfire

Tags: python, gpu, gpgpu, pow, arrayfire

According to the [arrayfire pow documentation](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__arith__func__pow.htm), `af.pow()` currently only supports powers (and roots...) of real arrays. No error is thrown, but I found that using `af.pow()` with complex input can cause a huge memory leak, especially if other functions are used as input (for example, `af.pow(af.ifft(array), 2)`).

To get around this, I have written the function `complexPow` below. This seems to run for complex arrays without the memory leak, and a quick comparison showed that my `complexPow` function returns the same values as `numpy.sqrt()` and the `**` operator, for example.

```
def complexPow(inData, power):
    for i in af.ParallelRange(inData.shape[0]):
        theta = af.atan(af.imag(inData[i])/af.real(inData[i]))
        rSquared = af.pow(af.real(inData[i]), 2.0) + \
                    af.pow(af.imag(inData[i]), 2.0)
        r = af.pow(rSquared, .5)
        inData[i] = af.pow(r, power) * (af.cos(theta*power) + \
                1j*af.sin(theta*power))
    return inData
```

Is there a faster way of doing parallel element-wise exponentiation than this? I haven't found one, but scared I'm missing a trick here...

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug. Can you report this on [github](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-python/issues).

Comment: Sure. I thought so. Will do tomorrow; I have a minimal working example showing the memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little faster without the parallel `for` loop:

```
def complexPow(inData, power):
    theta = af.atan(af.imag(inData)/af.real(inData))
    r = af.pow(af.pow(af.real(inData), 2.0) + 
                af.pow(af.imag(inData), 2.0), .5)
    inData = af.pow(r, power) * (af.cos(theta*power) + \
                1j*af.sin(theta*power))
    return inData
```

Tetsted for 4000 iterations over a `dtype=complex` array with dimensions `(1, 2**18)` using nvidia Quadro K4200, Spyder 3, Python 2.7, Windows 7:

**Using `af.ParallelRange`:** 7.64 sec (1.91 msec per iteration).

**Method above:** 5.94 sec (1.49 msec per iteration).

**Speed increase:** 28%.